# Inverse Laplace transform with an arbitrary parameter

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to find this:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}(s^nF(s))=?,
\end{equation}
where the parameter $n$ can be an arbitrary value. I know when $n$ is a positive integer, it can be written as a differentiated form; while when $n$ is a negative integer, it can be written as a integrated for. But can a general form be presented? Thanks!